# Local variable in AngularJS view

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and not sure how to solve the following problem: I want to create a simple year-month based menu:

- 2015

  - Aug
  - Jul
  - ...
- 2014

  - Dec
  - ...

Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.dateItems = [{date: <date_object>, year:<year_as_string>}, {date: <date_object>, year:<year_as_string>}, ...]
```

**View:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" ng-init="year = '0'">
    <div ng-repeat="item in dateItems">
        <span ng-if="item.year !== year">
            <li role="menuitem">{{item.date | date:'yyyy'}}</li>
            <!-- change local variable "year" (see ng-init above) to item.year -->
        </span>
        <li role="menuitem">{{item.date | date:'MMM'}}</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

How can I change the `year` variable?
Or is there a better solution instead of a local variable?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @MadScone I have a good solution for the shown case. But I want to generalize the question:

```
<div ng-init="foo = 'bar'" ng-repeat="item in myItems">
    ...
    <div ng-if ...>
        <!-- set foo to another value -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to change the value of `foo` in the loop? Or is there another way instead of `ng-init` to create a local variable used only in the view (not bound to a controller)?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off grouping your data by year since that's how it will be displayed.

**Controller**

```
$scope.dateItems = [
  {year: 2015, months: [new Date(), new Date()]},
  {year: 2014, months: [new Date(), new Date()]}
];
```

**View**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in dateItems">
    {{ item.year }}
    <ul ng-repeat="month in item.months">
      <li>{{ month | date:'MMM' }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution, I will implement it as shown. But apart from this example: Is it possible to use a local variable in a view?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. `year` is in your `dateItems` data, why do you want to create another "local" variable?

Comment: Please see my EDIT above. I hope it makes my question more clear.